# Find instance of google maps

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I'm working on a wordpress website and there is a google maps instantiated that I have to use to do some other stuff with.

I can't however find the instance of the google map.

The code where the map is instantiated is here http://pastebin.com/HsjiszGh

I literally checked every object in the console but there is no google maps instance to be found. Anyone has any clue how I can target that specific map without knowing what variable name it's hooked to?

Comment: Are you not just looking for the children of `.rwmb-map-field`? Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: This website uses a plugin to add custom meta boxes. Normally I would make the meta boxes myself but since this is already functional I don't want to redo everything. There is a google maps instantiated with this.map = new google.maps.Map.

I need that this.map variable cause I want to add more stuff from the API to that specific map that is rendered by already executed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like your map might be stored in the data attribute of elements with the class `.rwmb-map-field`. Try something like this:

```
$( '.rwmb-map-field' ).each(function(){
    var map = $(".rwmb-map-field").data("mapController").map
    console.log("Google Map: ",map)
})
```

Comment: Console log says:
Google Map:  undefined

When i remove the initMapElements.map part I get the rwmb-map-field object which has a map in it. 
What does that initMapElements.map de?

Comment: @Jebble my mistake, I believe I fixed it. Just be sure to only run it AFTER the map has been initialized.

Comment: I just removed the entire initMapelements.map and used the map.map instead. This is working perfect. I didn't knew objects could be stored inside the data attributes. How did you find out about this and where did you find the mapController string?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Jebble I found the code to initialize a google map on line 42, which I noticed was being added to the prototype of objects created using the `MapField` constructor. Did a quick search and found line 192 where the variable `field` is initialized as an instance of `MapField` and then noticed line 197, where `field` is added to the dom attribute via jquery.